# (CSS) How to change visibility of hidden element to visible, by hovering over a different element, without making a dummy element

Tags: css, hover, visibility

I am trying to show the loading progress on Youtube only when I hover over the progress bar.

Currently I am trying to use this:

```
.ytp-chapter-hover-container{
    visibility:hidden;
}

.ytp-progress-bar:hover ~ .ytp-load-progress{
      visibility: visible;
}
```

.ytp-load-progress is hidden because it is a child of .ytp-chapter-hover-container

As a sanity check when adding

```
 .ytp-load-progress{
      visibility: visible;
}
```

.ytp-load-progress does become visible, while.ytp-chapter-hover-container remains hidden

Here is an image where you can see that while .ytp-progress-bar is hovered, .ytp-load-progress is still not visible

[Hovered Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KEQA.png)

For reference, here is what it should look like:

[Hovered & Always Visible Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4HeR.png)

Comment: Please include your HTML also.

Comment: there is no added html, I dont work at google and I cant just add something to youtube

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.